# Joining relations with Ruby Object Mapper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datamapper, ruby-object-mapper

I have a little ["just for fun" Rails app](http://golf.riesd.com) that I am migrating from Active Record and SQLite to Ruby Object Mapper. This is mostly a chance for me to explore the way that the data mapper pattern affects my code.

I have a Course model, a Game model and a Score model. When calculating course records I need to get a course object along with all of its associated games and all of the scores for each of those games.

I found [an example of creating a joined relation](https://github.com/rom-rb/rom-relation/blob/93a771cf37a5aaf46072da2e35c073413384cb4e/spec/integration/schema_definition_spec.rb) but then I couldn't seem to find any examples of how to write a mapper for that relation so I'm not able to actually get that data back out.

My ROM schema looks like this:

```
base_relation :courses do
  repository :main
  attribute :id,          Integer
  attribute :name,        String
  attribute :created_at,  Time
  attribute :updated_at,  Time
  key :id
end

base_relation :games do
  repository :main
  attribute :id,          Integer
  attribute :course_id,   Integer
  attribute :played_at,   Time
  attribute :created_at,  Time
  attribute :updated_at,  Time
  key :id
  key :course_id
end
```

And I want to do a query where I can get a given course with all of its related games. Something like:

```
env[:courses].restrict(id: 1).join(env[:games]).one
```

But I haven't been able to find the right syntax for specifying a join, I just know that axiom supports joins in memory.

Does anyone know of a good example of doing reads and write with joined data from Ruby Object Mapper?

Comment: so right now you are using Ruby Object Mapper with a Redis Store? I am a little confused about what you have and what you want to achieve. it would also be helpful to post some example code to get a grasp of what you are trying to do.

Comment: @phoet Sorry for muddying the waters, redis is irrelevant for the purposes of this question. I am actually using [axiom-redis-adapter](https://github.com/hqmq/axiom-redis-adapter?source=c) in production and a simple [yaml adapter](https://github.com/solnic/rom-demo/blob/master/lib/yaml_adapter.rb) in my tests. I've edited the question above to include some sample code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently ROM doesn't support mapping joined relations OOTB. There's a new feature coming up in axiom called nest/unnest that ROM will use to map joined relations in a sane way.

Right now it would require a lot of hackery that's why we decided to postpone that feature and wait for axiom's nest/unnest.

Comment: I should add that work on nest/unnest is proceeding in this pull request: https://github.com/dkubb/axiom/pull/40